# How to display a custom block as a pop on home page?

Tags: blocks, javascript

I have a custom block created, it contains 3 links in it. Now I want to display that block as a popup on home page. I looked at the [Popup](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup) module but it didn't work.

Comment: You should give a liitle more info, why popup module does not work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the functionality of a Splash screen?

If so why don't you have a look at the [Splashify](https://www.drupal.org/project/splashify) module. It gives you quite a lot of options right out of the box.

If you are using Drupal 6; the [Splash](https://www.drupal.org/project/splash) module might be a better bet.

Answer (score 2):

There are other modules which provide you the popup functionality.

1. [Popup message](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_message)

> Display popup message for users once per browser session. Based on
>   javascript code:
>   http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-...

2. [Lightbox2](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2)

> The Lightbox2 module is a simple, unobtrusive script used to overlay
>   images on the current page. It's a snap to setup and works on most
>   modern browsers.

3. [Shadowbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/shadowbox)

> Shadowbox is a JavaScript modal media viewer application for viewing
>   images, video, Flash and other content in a modal window.